# How is this question off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Recommended UI/UX conference in the UK?

[Recommended UI/UX conference in the UK?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1152/recommended-ui-ux-conference-in-the-uk)

Sruly thinks it is off topic because "This question in not a UI question it is a "UI related" question." Please tell me where this site is a site for "UI questions" and not "UI related questions". The only definition for the site is "User Interface - Stack Exchange is for user interface researchers and experts." This question seems like a perfectly on-topic question for "user interface researchers and experts".

In addition, I don't see how a "UI related question" is that different than a "UI question". Even Sruly (the person saying this question is off-topic) cannot tell the difference:

> @Charles **this is not a UI related question**. 
>   It is a question directed at
>   the UI community. and btw "because
>   that's how Stack Overflow does things"
>   is a valid response IMO

Followed by:

> @Charles This question in not a UI
>   question **it is a "UI related" question**. 
>   It is close enough to the
>   topic at hand and interesting enough
>   to the users of this site that it will
>   not be closed, but it is not 100%
>   on-topic. If you want to argue that
>   this should be considered on topic
>   write about it on Meta

Emphasis in both is mine to prove the point.

**Update:**

Here's another question that is "not a UI question". It is a "UI related question". Why was this one not made community wiki, under Sruly's supposed criteria?

[How to become a User Experience Designer?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/479/how-to-become-a-user-experience-designer/500#500)

Comment: Regardless of the whole argument, I think that the question is on topic.

Answer (score 2):

We can't tell you that. This site is in beta and as such its rules and conventions are still under development. If you have something to contribute, which you apparently do, then that will be considered by the community in its definition of how we should treat questions like this.

Personally I think we should adhere to what Patrick alluded to in the comments for that question: list questions on UI have so far been CW'd, and this question was also a list question. I agree that list questions should be community wiki since users are encouraged to provide multiple answers of which none can objectively be "correct" given that the purpose of the question is to provide as much information as possible, not necessarily correct information.

Further, the issue at hand was not whether it was an on- or off-topic question; it was whether it should be CW'd or not. I think some wires got crossed in your exchange with Sruly and you got distracted into the semantics discussion around "UI related".

Comment: Nope, Sruly clearly stated that the question is off-topic for the site, which is why he said it should be community wiki. Then he proceeded to contradict himself and muddy the waters further. That means that the issue at hand is both CW and off- vs. on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned [here](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64/whats-the-difference-between-uxexchange-com-and-this-site), [uxexchange](http://uxexchange.com) may be disappearing some time in the near future.  If that is the case, overlap isn't an issue.  The topic is certainly of interest to the community.

I think the real issue still at hand is the overlap between uxexchange and this site.  To prevent overlap, we would need to focus exclusively on interfaces themselves.  If that was the case, this question would have belonged on uxexchange because it deals with the field of User Interaction/Experience.